# How do I pass a class to a generic without hardcoding the class?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I'm using [Bryan Tubbs' excellent code for populating a list generically](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827984/Generically-Populate-List-of-Objects-from-SqlDataR). That all works great.

In his code he passes the employee class to his `GenericPopulator` method.

```
var employeeList = new Classes.GenericPopulator<employee>().CreateList(reader);
```

I am trying to come up with an even more dynamic solution. How would I pass the `employee` class generically? Or maybe it's dynamically? Or maybe I have to use reflection? It seems like there's a way to do this but I just can't quite get the syntax correct. I've tried passing the class, typeof(class), the type, an object of that type, and probably a few other guesses. I can't get any of them to work.

I have a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAVwpe)...

Line 44 works by passing `MySchool`. But what I really want is for line 51 to work. If I comment out 44 and uncomment 51 Visual Studio gives a cannot implicitly convert type error (in Fiddle it instead gives a type or namespace not found error). What do I need to do to line 51 to pass `MyClass` to `GenericGetList<T>` correctly? And obviously if 51 needs to be changed perhaps the `GenericGetList` method needs a tweak as well.

The ultimate goal, if you haven't figured it out, is to be able to pass any class to `GenericGetList<T>` and have it work for that class. So from `GetListMySchool` I could fill a list of `IList<MySchool>` while from `GetListMyTeacher` I could fill a list of `IList<MyTeacher>`. `GetListXXX` can have the class hard coded into it but `GenericGetList` needs to work with whatever class is passed to it. Is this possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Editing line 32 to change it as Megatron suggested to

```
IList<MySchool> myList_Dynamic = new GenericGetList<MySchool>().GetList();
```

does certainly work for the code I originally posted. However the reason I'm calling `GetList_Dynamic` in line 34 is because in my unsimplified/unfiddled version of code my `GetList` function needs to be passed a SqlDataReader.

The `GetList_Dynamic` function gets the data reader and then calls `GetList`. So I've modified the Fiddle code to show `GetList` receiving a SqlDataReader parameter. That requires I change line 44 to pass the datareader and I added the datareader in line 42. Code to call the database, populate the reader, handle errors, etc would go between line 42 and 44.

So back to Megatron's idea of simply editing line 32...I don't have the datareader at that point to be able to pass it to the `GetList` method. Hence my desire to pass *something* on line 34 that could be used later once I've got my datareader all populated.

I have updated the Fiddle to include the SqlDataReader.

Comment: You can use an interface to do this.

Comment: Why are you making a new method to do the same thing you're already doing? just use `IList<MySchool> myList_Dynamic = new GenericGetList<MySchool>().GetList();` instead of `IList<MySchool> myList_Dynamic = new List<MySchool>(); GetList_Dynamic(new MySchool(), ref myList_Dynamic);`

Comment: Magnetron, I apologize. When I simplified my code to strip out the database access so I could Fiddle it I simplified it a bit too much. Let me work on getting the example to show why I need to call the intermediate method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception when learning to use generics. Generic types must be declared at compile time; they cannot be set at run time, because the whole point of using generics is to ensure type safety. The compiler is making sure that when `<Employee>` is the type parameter for `GenericPopulator`, then `CreateList` will return `List<Employee>`. In your fiddle, it has no idea how it's supposed to convert `MySchool` into `MyClass`. Thus, it's simply not possible to do what you're asking.

You probably need to read up on generics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/